# Using \today in \hyperref package

Tags: xetex, pdftex, hyperref, datetime

Posting a question for the first time so please let me know if I missed anything.

I am working in a LaTeX document and here is what I want to achieve using the hyper ref package:

Have a URL that is linked to my website and has today's date embedded for referral tracking. For example, the URL should look like:

https://example.com?ref=text-2ndOct2020

Basically, adding "ref=text-date" allows me to track where the link was clicked from to get to my website. I want to use this for manual A/B testing of the content, the date in the referral helps me determine the version that did better.

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass[letter,oneside,10pt]{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[ddmmyyyy]{datetime}

\begin{document}

\href{https://example.com?ref=text-date}{example.com}

\end{document}
```

This works, but what I'd ideally like to do is:

```
\href{https://example.com?ref=text-\today}{example.com}
```

so that the date can auto-update when I compile it for that particular day, the key being using `\today` to add today's date automatically to the link.

When I do use `\today` in `\href` in this particular solution, I get the following error:

```
Undefined control sequence. }
line 107: Undefined control sequence. }
line 107: Undefined control sequence. }
.
.
.
line 107: Undefined control sequence. }
```

I am using TeXStudio with a 2019 TeX-Live distribution, and compelling my document using XeLaTeX.

I am open to any solution but using `\today` is what came to my mind, I'm sure there are better ways to do this (if the `\hyperref` package supports it). Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.  This is an excellent first question.  Usually, hyperref should be one of the last packages loaded (with very few exceptions).  But I doubt that is what is causing your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what I tried:

```
\documentclass[letter,oneside,10pt]{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[ddmmyyyy]{datetime}

\begin{document}

\href{https://example.com?ref=text-\today}{example.com}

\end{document}
```

Running this (I have a newer install), I don't get the errors that you're getting, but the URL comes out as:

```
https://example.com/?ref=text-%5Cprotect%20%5C@day%20=%5Cday%20%5Crelax%20%5C@month%20=%5Cmonth%20%5Crelax%20%5C@year%20=%5Cyear%20%5Crelax%2000/00/0
```

which is obviously not what we want.

The problem here is that the `datetime` package is doing all kinds of generalized things and expecting to produce text and not a token sequence.

So instead, let's go for a specialized but simplified version of what `datetime` does. Drop the `\usepackage` and instead do:

```
\renewcommand{\today}{\ifnum\day<10 0\fi\the\day \ifnum\month<10 0\fi\the\month\the\year}
```

which gives the desired URL.

Comment: Thank you so much. I tried the MWE in Overleaf & got the garbled URL you mentioned above. I then tried your solution in my local env and it wasn't working, even though it worked in Overleaf.

So I updated my TeXStudio from 2.12.6 to 3.0.1 and to Tex-Live 2020.

It still didn't work, so I used your `\renewcommand` and changed it to:


`\newcommand{\trackdate}{\ifnum\day<10 0\fi\the\day \ifnum\month<10 0\fi\the\month\the\year}`

and then also changed `\today` to `\trackdate` when using `\href`.


Thanks so much for your perfect solution! I wouldn't have been able to figure it out.

Comment: Wanted to add further to this already wonderful solution by Don Hosek. The current date format gives "DDMMYYY" –– what I was trying to achieve. I further amended the command to match "YYYY-MM-DD", so just leaving this solution out there for anyone else wanting to do a similar thing in the future. Here is the updated command:
`\newcommand{\trackdate}{\the\year-%
 \ifnum\month<10 0\fi\the\month-%
 \ifnum\day<10 0\fi\the\day}`